# I want to upload and save image in database but when i try to do it Call to a member function images() on null error shown up

Tags: laravel-5

```
I am beginner in laravel and i want to make image uploading and saving app.
Everything is going cool but as i try to upload images it isnot saved to database.
But in public/gallery/images folder images are present.How this is possible without saving in database.
```

When i try to upload following error shown up:
FatalErrorException in GalleryController.php line 71:
Call to a member function images() on null

```
My controller is:

public  function doImageUpload(Request $request){
        //get the file from the post request
        $file = $request->file('file');

        //set my file name
        $filename = uniqid() . $file->getClientOriginalName();

        //move the file to correct location
        $file->move('gallery/images',$filename);

        //save image details into the database
        $gallery = Gallery::find($request->input('gallery_id'));//get the gallery_id
        $image = $gallery->images()->create([
              'gallery_id'=>$request->input('gallery_id'),
              'file_name'=>$filename,
              'file_size'=>$file->getClientSize(),
              'file_mime'=>$file->getClientMimeType(),
              'file_path'=>'gallery/images/' . $filename,
              'created_by'=>1,
            ]);
My view is:
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form action="{{url('image/do-upload')}}"
            method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>Select image to upload:</label >
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value={{ csrf_token() }}>
        </form>
    </div>
and my image model is:
class Image extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
      'gallery_id','file_name','file_size','file_mime','file-path','created_by'
    ];

    public function gallery(){
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Gallery');
    }
```

}
Being new to laravel i didnt get the actual error meaning Call to a member function images() on null??
How to fix this?

Comment: That's a PHP error, not laravel. It's literally what it says, `$gallery` object is `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do a log debug on `$gallery` after you use the find method, there's a good chance it's not initialized, if the `find` method fails to find the id you've given it, it returns `null`
a good practice would be to verify you get an object back and verify your input contains gallery_id and that it is a number > 0

```
if ($request->has('gallery_id') && intval($request->input('gallery_id'))>0){      
  $gallery = Gallery::find($request->input('gallery_id'));//get the gallery_id
  if ($gallery){
     $image = $gallery->images()->create([
           'gallery_id'=>$request->input('gallery_id'),
           'file_name'=>$filename,
           'file_size'=>$file->getClientSize(),
           'file_mime'=>$file->getClientMimeType(),
           'file_path'=>'gallery/images/' . $filename,
           'created_by'=>1,
           ]);
  } else {
    return Response::make('no gallery found with this $request->input('gallery_id') gallery_id',404);
  }
} else {
  return Response::make('invalid gallery_id as input',400);
}
```

you could also create the image via the Image create method as is instead of using the gallery relationship, that would have created an image probably with the gallery_id of 0 if the galley_id input is incorrect.

```
$image = Image::create([
           'gallery_id'=>$request->input('gallery_id'),
           'file_name'=>$filename,
           'file_size'=>$file->getClientSize(),
           'file_mime'=>$file->getClientMimeType(),
           'file_path'=>'gallery/images/' . $filename,
           'created_by'=>1,
           ]);
```

Comment: i use your code it gives FatalErrorException in GalleryController.php line 82:
syntax error, unexpected 'gallery_id' (T_STRING) error @Cptmaxon

Comment: if i use only image create method then wont it effect the relation between two models gallery and images @Cptmaxon

Comment: I use Image method but it voilets integrity constraints.SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'gallery_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `images` (`gallery_id`, `file_name`, `file_size`, `file_mime`, `created_by`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, 567ed9e6d85d7IMG_2374.JPG, 1582936, image/jpeg, 1, 2015-12-26 18:18:15, 2015-12-26 18:18:15))

Comment: I am confused why it isnot taking gallery_id .if I randomly put gallery_id=>1 or 2 it wont show error so where code got mistaken.Can u please suggest sir@Cptmaxon

Comment: you got 3 options for the error , either gallery_id isn't sent in the post parameters, or it's not number or it's a number that doesn't translate into gallery_id that exists in your database. can you try to write into log the values of the request input? something like `json_encode($request->input)`

Comment: yes it works thank you @Cptmaxon for help. Will u explain how that works when i include json_encode.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you resolved the problem, but I had the same issue and I found the solution.

When you send a form, you need to put a hidden input .

```html
<input type"hidden" name="gallery_id" value="{{ $gallery->id }}">
```

I'm sure you work on the same project as me, DropZone Gallery, if so I think you have the solution